# Why is my call of a nim template not simply expanding the template code?

Tags: templates, nim-lang

Working in Nim, my intuition for templates is that, at compile time, they are simply expanded into their code (with the appropriate substitutions). But the following code:

```
type
    New_Type = ref object of RootObj

template Template_Procedure(T: untyped, vProc: bool = true) = 

    proc ProcedureA(self:var T, vInt: var int): int 

    when vProc == true:
        proc ProcedureA(self:var T, vInt: var int): int =
            var tReturn = vInt * vInt 
            return tReturn

    proc ProcedureB(self: var T, vInt: var int): int = 
        var tI = ProcedureA(self, vInt)
        return 2 * tI 

Template_Procedure(New_Type, vProc = false)

proc ProcedureA(self:var New_Type, vInt: var int): int =
    var tReturn = vInt * vInt * vInt
    return tReturn

var tNew = new(New_Type)
var tInt = 5
echo $ProcedureB(tNew, tInt)
```

gives the error:

`` test3.nim(9, 10) Error: implementation of 'test3.ProcedureA(self`gensym0: var New_Type, vInt`gensym0: var int)' expected ``

If however I instead call

`Template_Procedure(New_Type, vProc = true)`

then there are no errors.

In contrast, if I manually substitute the text of the template in for the place where it is called, then the opposite occurs. I.e. the code compiles if I substitute false for vProc and I get the error

`Error: redefinition of 'ProcedureA'; previous declaration`

if I substitute true for vProc.

Can someone explain to me where my intuition is incorrect regarding templates? (or give me appropriate references)

Also, is there a way to write code which at compile time is simply expanded?

Specifically I would like to be able to call Template_Procedure(X, vProc = false) where X is a type and then, for appropriate types X, manually write specific

`ProcedureA(self: var X, vInt var int): int`

procedures. And for other X simply call Template_Procedure(X) and not have to manually define ProcedureA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The forward declare never gets an implementation as templates are hygienic. Although they both appear to have the name `ProcedureA` since you are inside template space they are not named the same. You likely should mark the template `{.dirty.}` or use `{.inject.}` on the procedures to inject the symbol names.

To the following question I do not know what you mean, templates are simply expanded.

Comment: Thank you! I was intuitively thinking that all templates were dirty and that was confusing me. I didn't realize that the internal names weren't seen outside the scope of the template. Adding the {.dirty.} pragma seems to make the template behave the way I want.